# datepicker not working jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

im trying to use jquery from online to generate my datepicker. in my markup it is:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

followed by

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#PStart").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in my header of my site master i have included:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

one point to note is that this date picker is nested within an update panel which is only suposed to update after completeing the form and the submit/save button is clicked. i have set shildren as triggers to false and update mode to conditional but its not being displayed, far less for making a choice.

Comment: It is working fine for me [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7JJNu/)

Comment: @abc123 not a valid demo since he is using asp net.

Comment: @Dom it proves that the issue isn't with the javascript, jquery, jquery-ui....the issue here is likely that his ID isn't `PStart` when the page is rendered...he needs to inspect element using a broswer...it is likely all mangled from asp.net...there are 3 solutions to this problem but i'd need him to validate it.

Comment: @New2This in your `Site.Master`, do you have a placeholder in the header? If so, is it before or after the header code you provided?

Comment: @Dom it is inside the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, it is impossible to say for sure. However, assuming there are no errors, the problem probably lies with `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` & `<asp:Content>` being called.

When using placeholders, asp controls change their IDs to the following format: *`{ContentPlaceHolderID}_ElementID`*.

I recommend either :

- changing `<asp:TextBox ID="PStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>` to `<input id="PStart" type="text"/>`
- inspect the page and find the actual id for that element (most likely `"#{ContentPlaceHolderID}_PStart"`).

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions!

---

*Site.Master:*

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SiteMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <div id="body">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*Default.aspx:*

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#MainContent_PStart, #PStart").datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:TextBox ID="PStart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
    <input type="text" id="PStart"/>
</asp:Content>
```

RESULT:

[image]